# Error in Hortonworks Sandbox with HDP 2.2.4.2

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I have Installed Virtual Machine 4.3.12 through that trying to connect Hortonworks Sandbox 2.2.4.2 but I am getting an error

"Failed to open a session for the virtual machine " 
No error Info .

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ProgressProxy
Interface: 
IProgress {c20238e4-3221-4d3f-8891-81ce92d9f913}

Please help to solve this issue ..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something went wrong with the installation. How did you install your sandbox - did you create your VM from scratch or did you import the Hortonworks .OVA file?

Try re-installing the VM. Click on your virtual machine manager -> File> Import Appliance > Select your .OVA file, then follow the prompts.

I recommend you use VirtualBox, it is straightforward to use.